# Scraping a webpage with a pop up alert auth in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping, popup, alert

I've been trying to scrape this [web page](https://www.deltron.com.pe) with python 3 where the login is like a pop up alert that you can see it [here](https://www.deltron.com.pe/login.php?), I tried using basic auth (https://(username):(password)@(url)), mechanize and [ntlm-auth](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm) unsuccessfully, or maybe I'm doing it wrong, I need a way to do it, I hope someone can help me with this...

Using ntlm-auth I get no errors, but the response is like the page without authentication, this is part of my code:

```
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import requests as rq

username = 'username'
password = 'password'    

url_prod = 'http://www2.deltron.com.pe/modulos/productos/items/producto.php?item_number=NBHP2B125LA'

sess = rq.Session()
sess.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)
resp = sess.get(url_prod)

print(resp, resp.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem with the same identification popup on another site and resolved it with the Basic Authentication of requests

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/